# neovim: breakindent results in slow insert mode

Tags: neovim, line-breaks, performance

I had the feeling that neovim was being sluggish in insert mode so I started bisecting my `init.vim`. Contrary to my expectations it looks like dozens autotrigger snippets were not the culprit but rater it's `breakindent` (and to some extent `linebreak` and `scrolloff=2`).

I ran some test of the form `:Time norm 1000isomething` * on a medium-size tex file (350 lines, 3400 words) with empty `init.vim` and these were the results:

- when `breakindent` is off this takes less than 2s
- with `breakindent` this takes 16s (same if I add `so=2`)
- with `breakindent` and `linebreak` it's 22s
- and if I add `so=2` it increases further to 27s

For comparison, on vim the times follow a similar pattern but the slowest I get is 5s.

I feel like 27ms is a lot of time to process 10 input characters so it seems like something is wrong here? Is this a bug in neovim? Is this a known issue / is there anything I can do to make this faster?

I'm using Neovim 0.5.1 on Ubuntu.

---

* using the `Time` command from`tpope/vim-scriptease`

Comment: Is this nvim-qt or just plain nvim?

Comment: Do you have `:set wrap`?

Comment: @Matt plain nvim in a terminal

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yes, it's enabled by default it seems.

Comment: These issues just seem like they would be less affected with nowrap, since breakindent and linebreak won’t apply